# Lisp - append to a list

Tags: lisp, common-lisp

I am new to lisp. I didn't properly understand how to implement append function on a list. I tried the following program.

```
(defvar temp)
(setq temp '())
(append temp (logxor 1 0))
```

temp seems to store only NIL value when it should be storing 1 in it.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

[`append`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_append.htm) returns the new value, it does not modify its arguments.
You need to use [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm):

```
(setq temp (append temp (list 1)))
```

or [`push`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_push.htm) (which adds to the *beginning* of the list, not the end!):

```
(push 1 temp)
```

You can also use [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm) for destructive appending, but you will *still* need [`setq`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/s_setq.htm) because you cannot destructively append to `nil`:

```
(defparameter temp nil)
(append temp '(1))
;; returns (1) but `temp` is still empty
(nconc temp '(1))
;; also returns (1) but `temp` is still empty
(setq temp (append temp (list 2)))
;; now temp is (2)
(append temp '(1))
;; returns (2 1) but `temp` is still (2)
(nconc temp '(1))
;; returns (2 1) and `temp` is now (2 1)
```

please note that one should not use quoted lists (like `'(1)`) when one plans to destructively append to them using [`nconc`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_nconc.htm), see [Why does an elisp local variable keep its value in this case?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/16670989/850781) for more information and links, especially [Issue CONSTANT-MODIFICATION](http://clhs.lisp.se/Issues/iss083_w.htm).