# Lisp: psetf not fully understood

Tags: common-lisp

I'm trying this in SBCL to flip the dotted pairs in the list:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x) (let ((num (random 2)))
                          (if (= num 0)
                             (psetf (cdr x) (car x) (car x) (cdr x))
                            x)))
                 '((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49)))
```

However I get this (ymmv):

```
(NIL (O . 24) NIL (R . 47) (K . 49))
```

which tells me `psetf` is not liking what I'm doing. As I understand, `psetf` is destructive and returns `NIL`. What am I not understanding here?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The behavior you observe is correct and expected:
[`psetf`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_setf_.htm) returns `nil`
and [`mapcar`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/f_mapc_.htm) places the return value
into the return list, so when `num` is 0, you get there `nil`,
and when it is 1, you get the original cell.

Easily fixed:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x)
          (when (zerop (random 2))
            (psetf (cdr x) (car x) (car x) (cdr x)))
          x)
        '((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49)))
==> ((B . 21) (24 . O) (P . 15) (47 . R) (K . 49))
```

actually, CL has a macro [`rotatef`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_rotate.htm)
just for your case:

```
(mapcar (lambda (x)
          (when (zerop (random 2))
            (rotatef (cdr x) (car x)))
          x)
        '((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49)))
==> ((21 . B) (O . 24) (15 . P) (R . 47) (K . 49))
```

Finally, please note that [modifying quoted data is a very bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16673364/850781):

```
(defparameter *alist-0* '((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49)))
(defparameter *alist-1*
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (when (zerop (random 2))
              (rotatef (cdr x) (car x)))
            x)
          *alist-0*))
(eq *alist-0* *alist-1*)
==> nil
(equal *alist-0* *alist-1*)
==> t ; !!!
(every #'eq *alist-0* *alist-1*)
==> t
```

i.e., the cells are the same, but the lists are different.

It would probably be better to consistently copy all cells:

```
(defparameter *alist-2*
  (mapcar (lambda (x)
            (if (zerop (random 2))
                (cons (cdr x) (car x))
                (cons (car x) (cdr x))))
          *alist-0*))
*alist-0*
==> ((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49))
*alist-2*
==> ((21 . B) (O . 24) (15 . P) (R . 47) (K . 49))
```

Answer (score 3):

Often one might want to avoid modifying the cons cells. `cons` new ones.

```
CL-USER 76 > (mapcar (lambda (pair)
                       (if (= (random 2) 0)
                           (cons (cdr pair)
                                 (car pair))
                         pair))
                     '((B . 21) (O . 24) (P . 15) (R . 47) (K . 49)))
((21 . B) (24 . O) (P . 15) (47 . R) (49 . K))
```

Comment: note that some cons cells in your result come from the quoted data.