# Unexpected modification of literal source of uncompiled lambda functions in CLISP?

Tags: lambda, common-lisp

I wrote the following function

```
(defun test (name)
  (let ((lst (list 'lambda '()
                   '(let ((slot name))
                     nil))))

     (setf (car (cdr (car (car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr lst)))))))) name)

     (let ((anonymous-function (eval lst)))
       (setf (fdefinition name) anonymous-function))))
```

If I run `(test 'a)`, the result is (on CLISP) `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT A)) NIL)>`;  if I run `(test 'b)` the result is `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT B)) NIL)>`.
And, until here, nothing strange. But when I run `(fdefinition 'a)` I get `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT B)) NIL)>`; and if I run `(fdefinition 'b)` I get `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT B)) NIL)>`.  Isn't it strange?  Shouldn't it be `#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT A)) NIL)>` the answer to `(fdefinition 'a)`?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Why does this function return a different value every time?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8962909/why-does-this-function-return-a-different-value-every-time)

Comment: Note: (car (cdr (car (car (cdr (car (cdr (cdr lst)))))))) can be written: (cadaar (cdaddr lst)).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're modifying literal data (and then using that data as body of the body of a lambda function), and that has undefined consequences.  See [Unexpected persistence of data](https://stackoverflow.com/q/18790192/1281433) for more about that.  It *is* a bit surprising that this is what's happening, but it appears that CLISP is saving the actual source (the value of **lst**) in the lambda function (rather than compiling it, and not copying it) so when you modify the code block, you see the results change in *every* lambda function that references the same code block.  There's only one instance of the list **(let ((slot name)) nil)**, and it is being shared by all the different lambda functions you're creating.  When you modify that single list, *all* of the lambda functions that use it see the change.

The *simplest* thing  (i.e., the smallest change to your code, but not necessarily the best solution) that you could to do get the results that you want would be to use [**copy-tree**](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/HyperSpec/Body/f_cp_tre.htm) to make a fresh code block:

```
  (let ((lst (copy-tree (list 'lambda '()
                              '(let ((slot name))
                                nil)))))
    ; ...
```

However, I think that the *best* way to handle this would just be to make use of Common Lisp's lexical closures and to avoid the mess with **eval** at all:

```
(defun test (name)
  (let ((f (lambda ()
             (let ((slot name))
               nil))))
    (setf (fdefinition name) f)))
```

```
CL-USER> (test 'a)
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT NAME)) NIL)>
CL-USER> (test 'b)
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT NAME)) NIL)>
```

While the results *look* the same, the functions are different because they capture *different* lexical environments, and so they do what they are supposed to.  E.g., look at what happens if you have the body return the value of the variable:

```
(defun test (name)
  (let ((f (lambda ()
             (let ((slot name))
               slot))))
    (setf (fdefinition name) f)))
```

```
CL-USER> (test 'a)
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT NAME)) SLOT)>
CL-USER> (a)
A
CL-USER> (test 'b)
#<FUNCTION :LAMBDA NIL (LET ((SLOT NAME)) SLOT)>
CL-USER> (b)
B
```

Comment: Thank you!
But I just tried with the copy-list and the result is the same;  I haven't tried the second method yet

Comment: @Matteo Sorry, I had the **copy-list** out too far, so it wasn't copying the whole list.  See the edit.

Comment: `copy-list` is out too far in that version as well. Replacing it with `copy-tree` would be a nice way to avoid the issue.

Comment: @m-n, yes, you're right. Of course,  the better option is still just to use the proper lexical closure