# Unexpected Behavior From Defun and Setf in Common LISP

Tags: common-lisp

The following code gives unexpected behavior:

```
(defun my-make-list () '(5 5 5))

(setf my-list (my-make-list))

(setf (car my-list) 3)

(my-make-list)

====> (3 5 5)
```

I set up my-make-list to be a function which always returns the list (5 5 5).
And yet when I use setf to assign the output of the function to my-list; and then use setf to change one of the items in my-list, it seems that the definition of the function changes.  It's now a function which always returns the list (3 5 5).

What's going on?

Comment: You're modifying literal data. See for example http://stackoverflow.com/q/8962909/5747548

Comment: Just to be clear, you need to write `(list 5 5 5)` to guarantee the behavior you want to have.